# Javascript setInterval and PHP Date()

Tags: javascript, php, date, setinterval

```
setInterval(function(){
        var ss = "<?php echo Date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?>";
        console.log(ss);
    }, 1000);
```

I have this little code. It takes Date one time and then all the time, result is the same.

```
(12) 2014-10-19 19:42:54
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: So.. what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to console.log server date and time, with 1 second interval

Comment: I hate to paste this video again, but I feel I have to: [Server-Side versus Client-Side](http://teamtreehouse.com/library/build-a-simple-php-application/getting-started-with-php/serverside-versus-clientside-2)

Comment: Javascript is client-side, PHP is server-side. You cannot mix them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to have a clock that increases by the second just like any other clock, you're gonna have to use javascript to implement it and you generally don't even need PHP to do it.

**Edited answer to use server time**

```
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i<10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}

var today=new Date('<?php print date("F d, Y H:i:s", time())?>');

function setTime() {
    today.setSeconds(today.getSeconds()+1)
    var year=today.getFullYear();
    var month=today.getMonth();
    var day=today.getDate();
    var hour=today.getHours();
    var minute=today.getMinutes();
    var second=today.getSeconds();
    minute = checkTime(minute);
    second = checkTime(second);
    month = checkTime(month);
    var time = year+"-"+month+"-"+day+" "+hour+":"+minute+":"+second;
    console.log(time);
}

setInterval(startTime, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var unixtime = <?=date('U')?>;
setInterval(function()
{


        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(++unixtime * 1000);
        var ss = date.getFullYear() + '-' 
                + (date.getMonth() < 9 ? '0' + (date.getMonth() + 1) : (date.getMonth() + 1)) + '-' 
                + (date.getDate() < 10 ? '0' + date.getDate() : date.getDate()) + ' ' 
                + (date.getHours() < 10 ? '0' + date.getHours() : date.getHours()) + ':' 
                + (date.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' + date.getMinutes() : date.getMinutes()) + ':' 
                + (date.getSeconds() < 10 ? '0' + date.getSeconds() : date.getSeconds());

        console.log(ss);
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: But, I want server time and not client time

Comment: @TaxTaxa Check my answer for server time

Answer (score 0):

Open rendered page source and you will see that resulted HTML looks something like this:

```
<script>
setInterval(function(){
    var ss = "2014-10-19 20:52:12";
    console.log(ss);
}, 1000);
</script>
```

PHP script is a server side program that outputs some HTML, which browser renders. So there is no surprise that you are facing this behavior.

If you want to create a timer in javasctipt you need to use [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object instance:

```
setInterval(function() {

    var d = new Date(),
        ss = d.getFullYear() + '-' + d.getMonth(); // etc.. formate you date

    console.log(ss);
}, 1000);
```

Refer [**`Date`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) documentation for available methods.

Comment: Thanks, I understand reason, but, I want server time and not client time.
Is it possible to get server time with js?

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your date in JavaScript in each setInterval call.

When you produce static code using php it defines JavaScript function with fixed value of date. Body of this function isn't overrided after each call, because there is generated specific date.